# Strange problem while adding years to date in a loop

Tags: php, date, loops, strtotime, mktime

```
$start_date = strtotime('2011-08-21');

    for($i=0 ; $i < 5; $i++)
    {
        echo "i = $i  and ";

        $start_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", $start_date), date("d", $start_date), date("Y", $start_date)+$i);
        echo date('Y-m-d',$start_date)."<br /><hr />";
    }

i = 0 and 2011-08-21
i = 1 and 2012-08-21
i = 2 and 2014-08-21
i = 3 and 2017-08-21
i = 4 and 2021-08-21
```

i didn't understand why after 2012 it doesn't add correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should do it like this if you want to add one year each time.

```
for($i=0 ; $i < 5; $i++)
{ echo "i = $i  and ";
  if($i>0)  $start_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", $start_date), date("d", $start_date), date("Y", $start_date)+1);
  echo date('Y-m-d',$start_date)."<br /><hr />";
}
```

Comment: how should i keep 2011?? in first loop it should not add +1

Comment: I would put the code inside a if($i>0), I edited the code above, please check.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* working correctly. You're adding an incrementing number to the year on each iteration.

```
i = 0 and 2011-08-21 // 2011 + 0
i = 1 and 2012-08-21 // 2011 + 1
i = 2 and 2014-08-21 // 2012 + 2
i = 3 and 2017-08-21 // 2014 + 3
i = 4 and 2021-08-21 // 2017 + 4
```

You should either

- `+1` instead of `+$1` to the year on each iteration
- **OR** don't overwrite `$start_date` on each iteration

#### Update (without overwriting)

```
for($i=0 ; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    echo "i = $i  and ";

    // $new_date holds the updated date without overwriting
    $new_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", $start_date), date("d", $start_date), date("Y", $start_date)+$i);

    echo date('Y-m-d', $new_date)."<br /><hr />";
}
```

Comment: how should i add without overwriting the $start_date?

Answer (score 1):

The following line

```
$start_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", $start_date), date("d", $start_date), date("Y", $start_date)+$i);
```

Should be

```
$start_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", $start_date), date("d", $start_date), date("Y", $start_date)+1);
```

Otherwise the year of the date is being increased by 1 then 2 then 3 the 4, as teh start date is being modified each time.